# MessageBox.Show -Embedded Code-SSRS Reports

Tags: vbscript, ssrs-2008

I am   viewing my deployed report at report server.

Suppose I have Embedded Code based on the link below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798(SQL.90).aspx

As this report are view form a web application

do the statement  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(“..”)

Work?

Will it cause error?

Comment: http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-reporting-services/error-being-thrown-when-using-the-msgbox-function-in-code-block-35896.shtml

Answer (score 0):

This is not a VBScript question. The embedded code is VB. I suggest you remove that tag. That said, message box modals will not work in web applications and yes the code will error.